# SeoShop API + how to add brand within the product in php with curl

Tags: php, api, curl

In SEOSHOP API (document at http://developers.seoshop.com/api/resources/brand )
, I created the product from API and want to add a brand within that product

How can i do ?

Please help

Comment: Also there is api for adding category  within product is http://developers.seoshop.com/api/resources/categoriesproduct  .... but not able to got anything how to add brand within product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a brand to a product by using the following endpoint and payload.

Endpoint: PUT https://api.webshopapp.com/nl/products/{productID}.json

{
  "product": {
    "brand": 1018742
  }
}

You can find the cURL and PHP examples on http://developers.lightspeedhq.com/ecom/endpoints/product/